# how to get all the id's using while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, fetch

i have a question here

how can i get all the id's from from the previous page and bring them to the next page using while loop

here is my first page:

```
        <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM grades_information JOIN student_information ON grades_information.student_information_id=student_information.student_information_id WHERE grades_information.subject_code='$subject_code'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<tr>';
        $student_numero = $row['student_information_id'];
        $grade_q1 = $row['grade_q1'];
        $grade_q2 = $row['grade_q2'];
        $grade_q3 = $row['grade_q3'];
        $grade_q4 = $row['grade_q4'];
        $final = $grade_q1 + $grade_q2 + $grade_q3 + $grade_q4;
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"stud_number\" value=\"$student_numero\">";
            echo'<td><div align="left">'.$row['student_lastname'].','.$row['student_firstname'].' '.$row['student_middlename'] .'</div></td>';
            echo"<td><div align=\"center\"><input type=\"text3\" minlength=\"2\" maxlength=\"5\" size=\"5\" name=\"grade_q1\" value=\"$grade_q1\"". (($subj_status = 'not for encoding'  && $date > $to1_quarter1 || $date < $from1_quarter1) ? "readonly" : "") . "></div></td>";
            echo"<td><div align=\"center\"><input type=\"text3\" minlength=\"2\" maxlength=\"5\" size=\"5\" name=\"grade_q2\" value=\"$grade_q2\"". (($subj_status = 'not for encoding'  && $date > $to2_quarter2 || $date < $from2_quarter2) ? "readonly" : "") . "></div></td>";
            echo"<td><div align=\"center\"><input type=\"text3\" minlength=\"2\" maxlength=\"5\" size=\"5\" name=\"grade_q3\" value=\"$grade_q3\"". (($subj_status = 'not for encoding'  && $date > $to3_quarter3 || $date < $from3_quarter3) ? "readonly" : "") . "></div></td>";
            echo"<td><div align=\"center\"><input type=\"text3\" minlength=\"2\" maxlength=\"5\" size=\"5\" name=\"grade_q4\" value=\"$grade_q4\"". (($subj_status = 'not for encoding'  && $date > $to4_quarter4 || $date < $from4_quarter4) ? "readonly" : "") . "></div></td>";
            echo'</tr>';
        }
        ?>
```

and here is my current code for fetching the id's

```
$stud_number = $_POST['stud_number'];
$section_name = $_POST['section_name'];
$subject_code = $_POST['subject_code'];
$employee_number = $_POST['employee_number'];
$curriculum_year = $_POST['curriculum_year'];
$grade_q1 = $_POST['grade_q1'];
$grade_q2 = $_POST['grade_q2'];
$grade_q3 = $_POST['grade_q3'];
$grade_q4 = $_POST['grade_q4'];
```

right now i only get one id

thanks for any help

Comment: That's because with each one you're overwriting the previous ID using that name. If you're building them in a while loop and just need the id numbers, put them into a named input field <input type='hidden' name='id[]'> value=<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?> and on the next page it'll be an array as $_POST['id'], accessible using a foreach($_POST['id' as $id){  echo $id}  etc

Comment: By using any of the [`mysql_*()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions you should be aware that **if** the server updates their software **your code will break** immediately as those function are removed. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. It has native support against [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).